# Extract preinstalled MS Office 2016 Pro Product Key before re-imaging?

Tags: microsoft-office-2016, software-activation

Is there a way to extract the MS Office 2016 Pro product key from a Dell Latitude? About to re-image and not looking forward to this process: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/re-install-preloaded-ms-office-2016/cbefea52-8303-4a39-aa00-3c3bb59c6dc4

I am not signed in to MS under  File->Account. I am not the original owner, just helping him. He does not have access to his previous email, seems disinclined/embarrassed to ask his previous partners for an email forward. Also- it is activated, gets updates fine and is used daily in his new job.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Nirsoft's [ProduKey](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) to find the current Office (and also Windows license) key.

However, Microsoft's *Windows Defender* considers that  malware, so you'll need to temporarily stop *Defender*, or run *ProduKey* from Windows PE or RE.

**Caveat:** This application has not caused any issue, in my own experience, but check in [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) to see what other anti-malware apps say.

Comment: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/e4604e0ee680370448c6a832856dff4a0255ca763672825a7a67a2a4662b9909

Comment: @RomeoNinov, exactly: "RiskWare.KeyViewer". Manufacturers consider that "an undesirable application." See  *Unauthorized Bread* by Cory Doctorow, a story about an owner's rights to their own property. Sorry, this is really tangential, and if anyone wishes, I'll remove this comment.

Comment: Software from Nirsoft is perfectly safe, the majority of the engines that determine it was malicious, were no name engines.  Of the few well known engines, it was likely tied to, something specific about the executable which is harmless but triggered by the security engines. If your still not convinced you can use some other software, or tell your friend, **to get that email**

Comment: Thank you Ramhound and Dr Moishe!